# Multi-seller Market Place - Show Same description and images for all products

Tags: magento-1.9, multi-vendor, marketplace

We are working on a multi-seller market place. We have an extension that allows as to do this. Sellers can register and can add products. Now we need to show same description and images for all sellers. For example seller A adds a product called Samsung Galaxy s7. Seller B also adds the same product. When the buyer search for the Samsung Galaxy s7 we need show only the product from seller which has the least price and also the Image and description should be same two product. Something like a master record for two products.

Is it possible to do this in Magento?

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no.

Magento has no multi-seller extension, therefore only one product exists with a sku (which is unique), therefore the problem you describe doesn't exist for core magento.

If you have this extension installed it depends how you know two products are the same. If you ask me, you want only one product and make sure the seller can only add prices.

Answer (score 0):

Selling same product by multiple vendor is surely possible in Magento . There are extensions which are offering the same functionality

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/marketplace-seller-price-comparison.html

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ON9-9PQMRQ

​I hope i have clear all your doubts still have any issue please comment

**PS - we are not self promoting our plugin or product , as user asked the questions specifically about marketplace product thats why i have added extension link with api link as well**